# Getting two Bootstrap Accordions to work within tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am having a problem trying to get two Bootstrap Accordions to work within separate tabs on the same page.

Basically, when I click through the first accordion all works as it should with the content collapsing and expanding as expected.

When it comes to the second accordion however, clicking on the links has no affect but it does apply my css styling to the element.

My question is how do I get it so that both accordions collapse and expand as per the expected behaviour of accordion#1?

```
<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <!-- ACCORDION NO.1 -->
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading edu1 active-state" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">HEADING 1</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading edu1" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">HEADING 2</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading edu1" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">HEADING 3</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    ***** SOME OTHER CONTENT *****
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        <!-- ACCORDION NO.2 -->
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading prev-emp activestate" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">HEADING 1</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="container panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading prev-emp" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">HEADING 2</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="container panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading prev-emp" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">HEADING 3</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                    <div class="container panel-body">
                        ***** SOME TEXT *****
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
        ***** SOME OTHER CONTENT *****
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery i am using;

```
$(function() {
  $('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('activestate')) {
      $(this).removeClass('activestate');
    } else {
      $('.panel-heading').removeClass('activestate');
      $(this).addClass('activestate');
    }
 });
});
```

I have replicated my issue here with accordion1 in tab 1 and accordion 2 in tab 3: http://jsfiddle.net/4yk7yzo9/1/

I am a no0b with jQuery so please play nicely and thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction

Comment: I believe it's not working as you have for example two divs with id of "collapseOne", "collapseTwo" etc. Make sure all elements have unique id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were simply repeating the same ID's for the accordions. And also, some of the `data-parents` were mixed up, [**Here is your Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yk7yzo9/2/)

See some of the changes to the 2nd accordion below:

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading prev-emp activestate" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">HEADING 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="container panel-body">
                    ***** SOME TEXT *****
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading prev-emp" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">HEADING 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="container panel-body">
                    ***** SOME TEXT *****
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Start of Previous Employment Tab #3 -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading prev-emp" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">HEADING 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="container panel-body">
                    ***** SOME TEXT *****
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, all the answers were right but @M.Doye was in first so will accept his answer but you all had the same solution. Thank you so much for your help and I should have noticed that sooner

Answer (score 1):

This duplicated id is the problem

```
 <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            ***** SOME TEXT *****
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used the same `ID` over and over again for each tabs. That is both your 3 accordions set has the similar `id` attributes.

Here is the working fiddle, updated your fiddle. :) 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lq26j75z/